# How to restore files recursively to a specific commit?

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I need to restore all `app.config` files in my repository to a specific commit, regardless on where those files reside. I know, that `git checkout` allows restoring a file or a folder to a specific commit, but is there a way to do that recursively without picking all files or using scripts?

I tried:

```
$ git checkout <commit> -- App.config

error: pathspec 'App.config' did not match any file(s) known to git

$ git checkout <commit> -- */App.config
error: pathspec '(Folder 1)/App.config' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '(Folder 2)/App.config' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '(Folder 3)/App.config' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '(Folder 4)/App.config' did not match any file(s) known to git
...
```

Those files actually *are* known to git, because if I go inside the folder and do:

```
git checkout <commit> -- ./App.config
```

It works, but only for this single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards will work:

```
git checkout abc123 -- '**/app.config'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to come up with a way to select your files, you can checkout only those files.

```
git checkout some-commit -- '*.c' '*.h'
```

I am using the quotes to keep bash from expanding them.

Also, sometimes things outside of git can give you a little hand:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r some-revision | grep some-file-name-filter | xargs git checkout some-revision --
```

Comment: What I need is specifically `app.config`. But `git checkout <commit> -- app.config` works in the current directory only.